# mod_rewrite with GET parameters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get

I'm trying to make a RewriteRule with get parameters. It's a simple example but still don't work.

```
RewriteRule ^/?localhost/([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

So if I go to `localhost/123` i want the `123` as `$_GET` in the test.php script.

Any idea why this fails? All other 'normal' RewriteRules work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localhost` is the domain, and doesn't belong in the `RewriteRule`. And I have changed your `[QSA]` to `[L,QSA]` so no further rules are executed.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If this needs to be restricted so it *only* rewrites if the domain is localhost, then you would use a `RewriteCond` like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That would be useful if you had a rewrite to perform under development only, but not when deployed to a production server.

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteBase /localhost
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ test.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

\d stands for [0-9]

Hope this helps.